# Passing data from functional component to app.js

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to React, still learning the basics of it.
I have a component in `students.js`:

```js
export const studentslist = () => {
  return [
    {
      name: "aaaa",
      surname: "aaa"
    },
    {
      name: "bbbbb",
      surname: "bbbb"
    },
    {
      name: "ccccc",
      surname: "ccc"
    }
  ];
};
```

How can I pass this list of students to my `App.js` into **state** and use it?

Answer (score 0):

`studentslist` is not a component as the function only returns an array of data, but it you want to use what the function returns as initial state of a component, you can import it in the component file and assign it to the state either in the constructor or in a class property.

**Example**

```js
// studentslist.js
export const studentslist = () => {
  return [
    {
      name: "aaaa",
      surname: "aaa"
    },
    {
      name: "bbbbb",
      surname: "bbbb"
    },
    {
      name: "ccccc",
      surname: "ccc"
    }
  ];
};

// App.js
import React from "react";
import studentslist from "./studentslist";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { studentslist: studentslist() };

  render() {
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>;
  }
}
```

```js
const studentslist = () => {
  return [
    {
      name: "aaaa",
      surname: "aaa"
    },
    {
      name: "bbbbb",
      surname: "bbbb"
    },
    {
      name: "ccccc",
      surname: "ccc"
    }
  ];
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { studentslist: studentslist() };

  render() {
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```